# How to make VirtualBox headless answer on rdp port?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, remote-desktop, debian

I'd like to run windows xp on RDP:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm winxp32 --vrdeport 3389
$ VBoxHeadless -s winxp32 -v on
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.1.18_Debian
(C) 2008-2012 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
(waiting)
```

in another window:

```
$ telnet localhost 3389
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Yes, I've read about extension:

```
$ sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.20-80170.vbox-extpack
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.20-    80170.vbox-extpack": Extension pack 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' is already     installed. In case of a reinstallation, please uninstall it first
```

Looked through all manuals and all help requests. No success. What's wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that vbox and addition had different versions. You cans see it in the console output.