# VirtualBox headless is running but not answering on rdp port(4001) on the same server

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, suse

I am running `SLES11 SP2` and  `VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.20_96996_sles11.0-1.x86_64` **is running in the same server**.

***facing problem to make VirtualBox headless answer on rdp port(4001) on the same server.***

Below are some information which might be helpful..

`obox01:~ # ps -aux |grep VBoxHeadless`

`Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html`

`vbox     12149  0.2  1.1 281328 91820 ?        Sl   12:47   0:19 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment obox01 --startvm 4380ee0b-ef72-42e3-acb8-5c30198118ad --vrde config`

`root     25860  0.0  0.0   5704   776 pts/2    S+   14:42   0:00 grep VBoxHeadless`

**result of telnet to this host..**

```
obox01:~ # telnet localhost 4001
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

***I am expecting VBoxHeadless will be listen on 4001 port, something like..***

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4001      0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  12149/VBoxHeadless
```

***Note: Follwed this..***

*[How to make VirtualBox headless answer on rdp port?](https://superuser.com/questions/466103/how-to-make-virtualbox-headless-answer-on-rdp-port)*

**Downladed and installed this extension pack Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.20-96996.vbox-extpack**

**but same result.**

Any idea what might be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE(24.12.2014):***
**Downladed and installed this extension pack Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.20-96996.vbox-extpack** 
worked after rebooting my system.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons are firewall and SELinux. The following commands will list the SELinux status and iptables firewall rules.

```
sestatus
iptables -L
```

You can also see these from Yast.